# Matching Buy Sell entries from two dataframes and creating a new one. Python 3.8 / W10

Tags: pandas, join, merge, matching

Python / Pandas.

Matching Buy and Sell entries row by row.

BuyDF and SellDF are obtained from one excel file and sorted as per ascending Time (column L).

The image shows how the matching has to be done.

Match Buy and Sell entries by Name following first in first out method.

Take very first entry (Name AAA) from BuyDF and match with very first / Top most entry (Name AAA) from SellDF and move the matching row from SellDF in front of corrosponding row of BuyDF and delete the row Sell DF.

Go back to BuyDF second entry and match SellDF entry and move the matching row from SellDF and move the matching row from SellDF in front of corrosponding row of BuyDF and the row is deleted from Sell DF ...... and so on.

For names which do not match leave the matching rows Blank.

The ascending order (Time / Column L) should not be changed to maintain first in first out.

Tried using merge but didn't work for me.

How to proceed ?

BuyDF

```
{'Date': {0: '2019-04-01', 1: '2019-04-01', 2: '2019-04-01', 3: '2019-04-01', 4: '2019-04-02', 5: '2019-04-02', 6: '2019-04-02', 7: '2019-04-02', 8: '2019-04-05'}, 'Name': {0: 'AAA', 1: 'AAA', 2: 'AAA', 3: 'AAA', 4: 'BBB', 5: 'CCC', 6: 'CCC', 7: 'BBB', 8: 'AAA'}, 'Ref': {0: 1, 1: 1, 2: 1, 3: 1, 4: 5, 5: 7, 6: 7, 7: 6, 8: 1}, 'Seg': {0: 'S', 1: 'S', 2: 'S', 3: 'S', 4: 'L', 5: 'XL', 6: 'XL', 7: 'L', 8: 'S'}, 'Trans': {0: 'buy', 1: 'buy', 2: 'buy', 3: 'buy', 4: 'buy', 5: 'buy', 6: 'buy', 7: 'buy', 8: 'buy'}, 'Qty': {0: 1, 1: 1, 2: 1, 3: 1, 4: 1, 5: 1, 6: 1, 7: 1, 8: 1}, 'Price': {0: 225, 1: 225, 2: 225, 3: 225, 4: 210, 5: 210, 6: 210, 7: 210, 8: 225}, 'Order ID': {0: 8249, 1: 111, 2: 654, 3: 111, 4: 888, 5: 444, 6: 444, 7: 888, 8: 111}, 'Trade ID': {0: 1010, 1: 1010, 2: 1010, 3: 1010, 4: 4645, 5: 132, 6: 132, 7: 4700, 8: 1010}, 'Time': {0: '2019-04-01 11:05:18', 1: '2019-04-01 13:05:18', 2: '2019-04-01 13:05:18', 3: '2019-04-01 13:05:59', 4: '2019-04-02 13:20:05', 5: '2019-04-02 13:35:02', 6: '2019-04-02 13:35:02', 7: '2019-04-02 14:20:12', 8: '2019-04-05 13:05:18'}}
```

SellDF

```
{'Date': {5: '2019-04-01', 6: '2019-04-02', 7: '2019-04-02', 8: '2019-04-02', 13: '2019-04-03', 14: '2019-04-05', 15: '2019-04-05'}, 'Name': {5: 'AAA', 6: 'BBB', 7: 'BBB', 8: 'BBB', 13: 'DDD', 14: 'AAA', 15: 'AAA'}, 'Ref': {5: 3, 6: 2, 7: 2, 8: 2, 13: 8, 14: 4, 15: 4}, 'Seg': {5: 'L', 6: 'X', 7: 'X', 8: 'X', 13: 'XS', 14: 'L', 15: 'L'}, 'Trans': {5: 'sell', 6: 'sell', 7: 'sell', 8: 'sell', 13: 'sell', 14: 'sell', 15: 'sell'}, 'Qty': {5: 1, 6: 1, 7: 1, 8: 1, 13: 1, 14: 1, 15: 1}, 'Price': {5: 210, 6: 210, 7: 210, 8: 210, 13: 210, 14: 210, 15: 210}, 'Order ID': {5: 555, 6: 222, 7: 222, 8: 222, 13: 999, 14: 555, 15: 555}, 'Trade ID': {5: 1640, 6: 1532, 7: 1532, 8: 1532, 13: 14623, 14: 1645, 15: 1645}, 'Time': {5: '2019-04-01 14:13:40', 6: '2019-04-02 13:10:32', 7: '2019-04-02 13:10:32', 8: '2019-04-02 13:10:32', 13: '2019-04-03 15:25:50', 14: '2019-04-05 14:41:45', 15: '2019-04-05 14:41:45'}}
```

[image]

Image posted for ease of understanding.